# Multiple Element Rollover Using CSS

Tags: css, hover, rollover

I need to have divs show `{border-bottom:solid 2px #F63}` when a list item is rolled over.  I played with `.whatever:hover .whatever {` but came up with nothing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your CSS should work; maybe there's something particular in the full code that's causing it to not work.  You should post a more complete copy of your CSS.

Comment: @Spencer if your `div`s are the elements you want to add the border and the list item is inside it, then it can't be done with css as you can't specify an element based upon it containing another element (AFAIK). if it is the other way around and your `div` is inside your list item then it should work. Like what @Jacob said.

Comment: Your list item `.whatever` must contain the div you want to style using that technique. There's a reason CSS is called _Cascading_ Style Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your CSS/HTML, it's hard/impossible to post a solution.  But as @James Khoury mentioned in the comment, you will need to place the `div` inside the `li`.  So something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">First
        <div class="first">
            First
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="second">Second
        <div class="second">
            Second
        </div>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div{width:50px; height:50px; 
    border:1px solid blue; 
    margin:1em;}

li a{display:block;}

li.first:hover div.first, li.second:hover div.second{
    border-bottom:solid 2px #F63;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/6rjd9/